# Reducing the size of final APK before submitting to the play store

Tags: android, performance, google-play, apk

My android application file size is huge, I've used Proguard and ImageOptim to reduce the size of images and code which isn't being used.

This is the buildtypes in my gradle:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I will also delete the mockable-android-jar before submitting.

I have also seen that the intermediates folder is big in size, I also cleaned it by deleting the extra png images which were not being used by the application (i.e: g+ png's and so on.)

[image: App build info]

What can I do which may help me shrink down this apk.

Edit: Made the following edits, which resulted intermediates to become 12.5 MB

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfigs "en"
}
```

Removes resources which are not meant for the english language.

Comment: what is your `src` folder size ??

Comment: You may check also https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: @Ironman the size is 124kb

Answer (score 3):

1. Extract your apk and check which folder is bigger in size.

Or you can use "Android Studio" Also to analyze your apk file :
[image]

3. Reduce your image files size and use vector drawables wherever possible.

Go through the following guides on apk size reduce :

- https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-1-anatomy-of-an-apk-da83c25e7003#.nlid8yvdb
- https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-2-minifying-code-554560d2ed40#.bayyfe7zd
- https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-3-removing-unused-resources-1511f9e3f761#.igywlhtem
- https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-4-multi-apk-through-abi-and-density-splits-477083989006#.9fgm8mryi
- https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-5-multi-apk-through-product-flavors-e069759f19cd#.ngg4dfe8i
- https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-6-image-optimization-zopfli-webp-4c462955647d#.elxsq9tcc
- https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-7-image-optimization-shape-and-vectordrawables-ed6be3dca3f#.m0p9rrl4t
- https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-8-native-libraries-open-from-apk-fc22713861ff#.mcytfj9y3

Comment: No need to "decompile" the APK. Just unzip it.

Comment: yes. Thanks. Also in android studio one new feature is added, Build -> Analyze APK